# how to create avro schema for nested collections?

Tags: java, avro, jsonschema

I do have a body like this -

```
{
    {
        "name":"abc",
        "eventName": "abc",
        "pl": {
             "name": "xyz",
             "age": 21,
             "address": {
                 "line1" : "h.no - ",
                 "line2": "state"
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to create a valid Avro schema for this kind of body.
I have found a example to create nested schema like this -

```
[
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Address",
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "streetaddress",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "city",
    "type": "string"
  }
]
 },


 {
"type": "record",
"name": "person",
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "firstname",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "lastname",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "address",
    "type": "Address"
  }
]
```

}
]

while I am providing this kind of schema, it's providing me error at below line -

GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);

Error is - org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a record schema:

Answer (score 2):

you can define your record like this to support nested objects.

```
{

    "type": "record",
    "name": "person",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "firstname",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "lastname",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "address",
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Address",
                "fields": [{
                        "name": "streetaddress",
                        "type": "string"
                    }, {
                        "name": "city",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```